# How to configure Azure AD SSO programmatically for gallery-based application?

Tags: automation, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, tableau-api

I need to configure Azure Active Directory SSO for Tableau Server gallery app as it is under MS documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/tableauserver-tutorial#configure-azure-ad-sso) programmatically. Are there useful powershell cmdlets / rest apis?

I create application from gallery using graph api from Step 1 on [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/application-provisioning-configure-api#step-1-create-the-gallery-application).
To get available templates:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applicationTemplates
```

To create template app:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applicationTemplates/{id}/instantiate
```

Now I need to configure SAML SSO from code and assign users. Is there an easy way to do that? I tried **Set-AzureADApplication** but it didn't do the job for me. The enterprise application is still not set.
Maybe it's not supported yet? I believe there can be some workaround. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there useful powershell cmdlets / rest apis?

Yes, but per my test, we need to do that into two parts.

1.Set the `Sign-on URL`, to do this, we need to call Microsoft Graph - [`Update serviceprincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

In the Graph Explorer, use the request below.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/<object-id of the service principal>

{
  "loginUrl": "https://azure.signtest.link"
}
```

[image]

**Note:** In the request above, you need to use the object-id of the service principal(Enterprise application), not the AD App(App registeration). You can find it in the Azure AD in the portal -> `Enterprise Application` -> find your `Tableau Server` -> get the `Object ID` like below.

[image]

2.Set the `Identifier` and `Reply URL`, we could do this via Powershell `Set-AzureADApplication`.

*Sample:*

```
$Identifiers = @(
    "http://www.tableau.com/products/server",
    "https://azure.idtest.link"
)
$ReplyUrls = @(
    "https://azure.rptest.link/wg/saml/SSO/index.html"
)
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <object-id of the AD App> -IdentifierUris $Identifiers -ReplyUrls $ReplyUrls
```

For the `object-id of the AD App`, navigate to the Azure AD in the portal -> `App registrations` -> find your `Tableau Server`. After running the command, the settings will map to the enterprise application.

[image]

**Check the result in the portal:**

[image]

**Update:**

Not sure if it is a bug, if I create a new app without setting the `Identifier` and `Reply URL` manually in the portal, then just use the powershell above to set them, they will not map to the portal.

But if we check the service principal(enterprise application) directly via Microsoft Graph, we can see the powershell actually affected the service principal.

[image]

If we configure the settings manually in the portal first, then use the powershell to update them with other values, it works.

[image]

And it looks there is no way to set the `Default Reply URL` via powrshell or API, if we set the `Reply URL` which is different from the one set manually in the portal, it will have a prompt like below.

[image]

But if we look into it, actually the `Default` option is checked.

[image]

**Update2:**

Eventually, I find the trick, it is not a bug, we just need to set the `preferredSingleSignOnMode` for the service principal first via Microsoft Graph, then we won't need to configure that in the portal manually.

Sample:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/<object-id of the service principal>

{
  "preferredSingleSignOnMode":"saml",
  "loginUrl": "https://azure.signtest.link"
}
```

Comment: Hi @joy-wang, thanks for your answer! I tested your solution. I managed to set Sign-On Url, but I had some error with **Set-AzureAdApplication** which gives me `Code: Request_ResourceNotFound` whit both `object-id of the AD App` and `enterprise object-id`. I even cannot find this app on the list `Get-AzureADApplication -All $true`. For example if I use  `Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal` and `Update-AzureRmADApplication` the app is there. But if I use `Update-AzureRmADApplication`, the enterprise app remains unset (ReplyUrls and IdentifierUris)...

Comment: @MichaelK. It should work, try to update the `AzureAD` module first, use `Update-Module -Name AzureAD -Force`. And if you pass the object-id of the AD App directly to the `Set-AzureADApplication`, will it work?

Comment: @MichaelK. After updating the module, if still not work, please make sure you login with the correct tenant, use `Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "<your-tenant-id>"` to login again.

Comment: You're right, I had a wrong tenant set. After `Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "<your-tenant-id>"`, `Set-AzureADApplication` didn't return an error, but Enterprise App is still unset when it comes to `IdentifierUris` and `ReplyUrls`

Comment: @MichaelK. Did you refresh the portal?

Comment: @MichaelK. And make sure you are checking the correct enterprise application corresponed to the AD App, you can navigate to the AD App in the portal -> click the `Managed application in local directory`, refer to https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPRi1.png

Comment: I refreshed the portal. Also correct enterprise app corresponds to the ad app

Comment: @MichaelK. Hi, previously, I set them manually in the portal first, so I could not reproduce this, I saw your new [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61179830/how-to-set-properties-of-azure-active-directory-service-principal-from-code), I can reproduce your issue with a new app, you could check my update.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Your answer is really helpful.

Comment: I verified your 2nd update and it worked as expected, thanks! :) I need to add some owners and users with `Default Access` role assigned and then add `SAML Signing Certificate` in 3th section in SSO yet. I think that it will be possible to achieve.

Comment: @Mike26 or Joy -- Can you possibly share a gist or such on how to do this process?  I'm just starting to automate creating the AD app via powershell and that would really help