# How to set properties of Azure Active Directory service principal from code?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, saml, service-principal

I have created AAD application from gallery. There is one in app registrations section and one in enterprise applications. App registrations application points to the enterprise app (managed application in local directory).

I want to configure SAML SSO for the enterprise app. There are a few required properties which have to be set.

[image: Saml sso azure configuration]

I am able to set `Sign on URL` (using graph api), but I cannot set `Identifier (Entity ID)` and `Reply URL`. I thought that this will do the job:

```
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <id of app from App registrations> 
         -IdentifierUris $Identifiers -ReplyUrls $ReplyUrls
```

but the enterprise app is untouched. Also `Set-AzureADServicePrincipal` doesn't seem to work for me.

There are no errors. Nothing changed on the portal after refresh. I am connected to correct tenant and have fresh modules installed.

I tried also with RM: `Update-AzureRmADApplication`, `Set-AzureRmADApplication`, `Set-AzureRmADServicePrincipal`, `Update-AzureRmADServicePrincipal`.
I also couldn't find a working graph api.

Is there a way to do this from code? Maybe I am just doing something wrong and it's working for you? I would be grateful for some help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but enterprise app is untouched.

Actually, the enterprise has been affected, we could check it via Microsoft Graph after using `Set-AzureADApplication`, it just not appear in the portal, <del>may be a bug, I am not sure</del>.

```
$Identifiers = @(
    "http://www.tableau.com/products/server",
    "https://azure.idtest.link"
)
$ReplyUrls = @(
    "https://azure.rptest.link/wg/saml/SSO/index.html"
)
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <object-id of the AD App> -IdentifierUris $Identifiers -ReplyUrls $ReplyUrls
```

[image]

If we set them in the portal at first time, then run the commands again, you will find it works.

[image]

And it looks there is no way to set the `Default Reply URL` via powrshell or API, if we set the `Reply URL` which is different from the one set manually in the portal, it will have a prompt like below.

[image]

But if we look into it, actually the `Default` option is checked.

[image]

### Update:

Eventually, I find the trick, it is not a bug, we just need to set the `preferredSingleSignOnMode` for the service principal first via Microsoft Graph, then we won't need to configure that in the portal manually.

Sample:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/<object-id of the service principal>

{
  "preferredSingleSignOnMode":"saml",
  "loginUrl": "https://azure.signtest.link"
}
```

Comment: I was able to get the properties that I had set. You're right. Somehow they didn't show up in the portal, but I could get them from the graph api. Yes, that might be some kind of bug. I assume that currently it's not possible to setup whole SAML from code without manual intervention to the portal. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, thanks again! Let's hope this will be fixed someday

Comment: @MichaelK. Hi, it is not a bug, I find the solution, please check my update. Also updated it in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099158/how-to-configure-azure-ad-sso-programmatically-for-gallery-based-application/61116473#61116473).